# JBimages plugin for TinyMce does not insert image

Tags: wysiwyg, tinymce-4, justboil.me

I am using the [justboil.me](http://justboil.me/) plugin for TinyMce 4 after reading all the documentation and followed step by step the instructions.
The plugin is uploading the images to the right path perfectly, but it does not show on the editor. And when I see the HTML output in tinyMce there is no image tag at all.

This is my **TinyMce** configuration:

```
<script src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
tinymce.init({
selector:"textarea",
plugins: [
"advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
"searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
"insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste jbimages"
],
external_plugins: {
    "jbimages": "http://root.flubby.org/apps/tiny_mce/plugins/jbimages/plugin.min.js"
    },
toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link jbimages",
relative_urls: false
    });
</script>
```

**Note**: I am running this script on a complete different domain. I don't think it should affect, since the plugin is running and uploading the image. Just without the last step of adding it to the contents.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot for reading =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code

```js
tinymce.init({
    imageupload_url: "../upload/",
    selector: "textarea",
    theme: "modern",
    language: "en",
    plugins: [
         "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
         "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
         "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor imageupload"
    ],
    content_css: "css/content.css",
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons imageupload", 
    relative_urls: false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> This is my configuration i hope help :)

```
   <script src="../js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
   <script>
   tinymce.init({
   height           : 240,
   width            : 900,
   selector         : "textarea",
   plugins      : "jbimages table link autolink charmap print preview searchreplace code",
   toolbar      : "undo redo | bold italic underline charmap searchreplace | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | styleselect table | link code | jbimages preview",
   menubar          : false,
   relative_urls    : false
   });
   </script>
```